# php sort multi dimensional array by value with different keys

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, search, multidimensional-array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => AL
            [country] => Albania
            [country_group] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => AT
            [country] => Austria
            [country_group] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => BE
            [country] => Belgium
            [country_group] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => BG
            [country] => Bulgaria
            [country_group] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => HR
            [country] => Croatia
            [country_group] => 1
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => CY
            [country] => Cyprus
            [country_group] => 1
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => CZ
            [country] => Czech Republic
            [country_group] => 1
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [id] => DK
            [country] => Denmark
            [country_group] => 1
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [id] => EG
            [country] => Egypt
            [country_group] => 1
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [id] => MF
            [country] => St. Martin
            [country_group] => 1
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [country_name] => Iceland
            [country_iso_code] => IS
            [country_id] => 98
        )
)
```

Now I want to arrange the array according to the value of the key country alphabetically so iceland should come on after Egypt but iceland has different key for its name country_name.

I have tried

```
usort($myArray, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['order'] - $b['order'];
});
```

It works with the same key name but if the key name is different it comes in the bottom.

There would be many more countries like iceland with the key country_name I want a function like

```
arrange($array);
```

and it would arrange the array alphabetically according to the keys country and country_name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, your logic is

> if element has `country_name` key - use it to sort, else - use `country` key

```
usort($myArray, function($a, $b) {
    $aName = !empty($a['country_name']) ? $a['country_name'] : $a['country'];
    $bName = !empty($b['country_name']) ? $b['country_name'] : $b['country'];


    return strcmp($aName, $bName);
});
```

**Another solution** is to iterate over `$myArray`, replace key `country_name` with key `country` where required and sort as usual.

Answer (score 0):

**Usort** is a good choice but when there is lack of **country** key just use **country_name**.

```
usort($countries, function ($a, $b) {
    return ($a['country'] ?? $a['country_name']) > ($b['country'] ?? $b['country_name']);
});
```